Is it possible to transfer files and copy text from VirtualBox with QNX to Windows 10 without Guest Addition?
I have a task like this: I have a virtual machine with QNX. There are old Fortran programs (hydrodynamic problems) there. I need to extract them and process them for Matlab.
The problem is that I can't copy text or transfer files to the Host system (in this case, it's Windows 10). Copying simply doesn't happen. Just like I can't create a shared folder.
This is a classic problem, and questions about it have been asked here many times. Usually, you need the Guest Addition and enable bidirectional clipboard and file transfer in the virtual machine settings.
In contrast, I already have the Guest Addition installed (this is indicated by the Secondary Master of IDE: ViBox Guest Additions.iso). I also set bidirectional settings and connected the Guest Additions disk image in the Oracle VM VirtualBox manager window.
The problem: copying and transferring still don't work. What's wrong?
Equipment: VirtualBox 6.0. with QNX and Windows 10.

Did you install the VirtualBox Extension Pack?

@DavidAnderson I don't know. I wasn't the one who installed it. Where can I see it?

Goto VirtualBox->Preferences, the select Extensions. See this image.

@DavidAnderson I looked. There is no extension pack.

I am reading the discussion (in the comments) between @grawity_u1686 and you. There is mention of having your QNX VM accessing a physical USB flash drive. While Guest Additions is not required to do this, installation of the VirtualBox Extension Pack is required. You need Administrator access to install this into the VirtualBox application.

The VirtualBox Extension Pack for VirtualBox 6.0 can be found here. You will need to know exactly which 6.0 you have installed. The VirtualBox Extension Pack is the same regardless of the the host operation system.

@DavidAnderson I installed the Extension Pack of the appropriate version. I installed it by connecting it to VirtualBox. In the USB settings, I enabled support for 2.0. and selected the device. But QNX still doesn't seem to see it (or rather, it's not visible in the QNX File Manager).

Is the device, physical USB port and cable all capable of USB 3 or faster?

@DavidAnderson Yes, all modern protocols are supported. David, I experimented with some console commands (trial and error from some USB connection guides). The flash drive was detected and is located at /fs/usb0. Now I can see all its contents in QNX.


I already have the Guest Addition installed (this is indicated by the Secondary Master of IDE: ViBox Guest Additions.iso).

No, that does not indicate "installed". It only indicates that you have inserted the installation CD into the virtual IDE CD-ROM drive – but that CD hasn't installed anything yet. (And it won't, because VirtualBox doesn't have any Additions for QNX.)
If your version of QNX supports it, instead create and attach a HDD image to copy the Fortran files into. (For example, create a VHD in Windows, format it using FAT32, then attach it as an IDE disk to the VM and transfer files. Afterwards, detach the disk and mount it directly in Windows.)

So it turns out that these Fortran files were created in QNX and were not transferred there? Am I understanding you correctly?

No, I have not said anything like that. There are other ways to transfer data besides copy/paste – the files could have been created in QNX, but they could just as well have been transferred over the network, or over serial port, or from another disk (floppy disk or IDE or CD or USB).

So these files could have been transferred to QNX from a flash drive or something similar? Hmm, maybe that was the case, I don't know for sure. But isn't Guest Addition needed for that?

No, Guest Additions only deal with VM-specific transfer methods – a flash drive isn't one of them; if VirtualBox emulates e.g. a USB stick or a floppy disk or an IDE HDD, those are already natively recognized by QNX and most other OS. That's how the guest would've read the Additions install .iso CD, after all. (They could've also been real disks in case the QNX system originally ran on a physical machine before being transferred into a VM.)

Then I need to check your proposal. Could you rite again briefly what needs to be done and how to configure a virtual machine with QNX to interact with a removable device? Of the equipment that I have, actually, a flash drive and a Windows host hard drive with a large amount of unoccupied memory, part of which could be allocated specifically for QNX. True, I tried something with the flash drive today, QNX did not detect it.

You can try using VirtualBox's "USB passthrough" to attach the flash drive. If the QNX version supports USB, it'll see the drive like a regular USB device. If not, then try creating a virtual disk (VHD) instead; that doesn't need any equipment. I'm generally not sure how QNX deals with hardware – does it see your VM as having a CD drive, at least?

I won't be able to do this test because the system unit doesn't have a CD drive.

Whether the system unit has a CD drive has nothing to do with the test. The last comment was about the virtual machine's CD drive, not the host system's.

Please read our correspondence under the main question. I managed to connect the flash drive using the Extension Pack. The system sees the flash drive and I can save files. It turns out that the initial question can be answered affirmatively (at least halfway, since copying text from QNX to Windows still hasn't worked).
